# TeeChart Standard VCL FMX 2023.38 for Delphi Alexandria 11.1 fails to properly install

Tags: teechart, delphi-11-alexandria

After installation, starting Alexandria 11.1:

Can't load package ...VCL FMX 2023.38\Delphi28.win32\Bin\DclTee928.bpl.  Cannot load package 'Tee928'.  It contains unit 'VCLTee.TeeConst', which is also contained in package 'Tee9280'.

Have other Delphi users run into this and did you find a solution?

(Fully uninstalled previous version of TeeChart before the installation was attempted).